# How to dismiss a viewController to rootViewController without showing any VCs in between dismiss process?

Tags: ios, swift

Let say I have the following VCs:

RootVC --> VC A --> VC B

I'm using present method to present view controller from RootVC to VC A then to VC B. Now I'm on VC B and I want to dismiss from VC B back to RootVC using

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

it works but I still see VC A shows up during the dismiss process. Then, I try this method

```
self.presentationController?.presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It also works to dismiss back to root VC but I still see VC A in process.

My question is is there a way to not show VC A during the dismiss process? I already try animated: false but still get the same result. Thanks!

Comment: Set `animated` to false?

Comment: You can definitely achieve this effect if you really want it. You obviously can't dismiss `A` in the background while viewing `B` because `A` is presenting `B`. So what you can do is create a custom dismiss animation specifically for `B` that snapshots the root and dismisses to that snapshot from `B`--to the user, it would look exactly like a dismiss straight to root. You can also just push from `A` to `B` and animate it to look like a present; therefore, dismissing `B` will take the user directly to the root. I personally don't think seeing `A` dismiss automatically after `B` would look bad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the change in the `modalPresentationStyle` to the `.custom`. The `custom` will allow you to view the `presentingViewController` view when the current visible controller's view is transparent.

Now when you want to go back to root view on the current presenting stack you need to call the method `dismissToRootViewController(animated: completion:)`.

In the implementation of this method will allow all intermediate presenting view controller view to be transparent which will give you dismiss animation from `VC c` to `RootVC`.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func dismissToRootViewController(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil) {
        var viewController = self.presentingViewController
        while viewController?.presentingViewController != nil {
            viewController?.view.alpha = 0.0
            viewController = viewController?.presentingViewController
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            viewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use this:

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

Comment: It's for navigation tho. I am hoping if there is a way for dismiss